# registerForActivityResult with RequestPermission in Fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'm changing old styled code for Activity Results, and got stuck on permission results. In fragment where users can pick one contact from a list and copy it's data, permission callback is not working at all, however activity result is firing callback... Here is simplified fragment class:

```
public class PeopleAddEdit_SubVen_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mActivityResult;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> mPermissionResult;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addedit_ppl_subven, container, false);
        ImageView contacticon = view.findViewById(R.id.contacticon_container);
        contacticon.setImageDrawable(AppLib.getAppDrawable(R.drawable.icons_88));
        contacticon.setOnClickListener(view1 -> processContact());
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;

        mActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            //processing data here
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                });
        mPermissionResult = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                        if (result) {
                            PeopleAddEdit_SubVen_Fragment.this.startProcessingContacts();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PeopleAddEdit_SubVen_Fragment.this.getActivity(), "No permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
    private void processContact() {
        int getContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (getContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mPermissionResult.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        } else {
            startProcessingContacts();
        }
    }
    private void startProcessingContacts() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        mActivityResult.launch(intent);
    }
}
```

When Contacts are not granted, after displaying popup to deny or allow Contacts, nothing happens regardless of choice. If I click button again (after I allow Contacts), I get contacts displayed, so activity result is firing callback, but permission callback is not fired at all, but permission is granting or denying, depending on choice, but not firing result.

In the build.gradle ​I have

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.0-rc01'
```

Any ideas why is not firing?

Comment: Note that you do not need `READ_CONTACTS` permission to use `ACTION_PICK` to select a contact, or to get information from `ContactsContract` about the contact that the user picks. You only need `READ_CONTACTS` if you are not using `ACTION_PICK` and are querying `ContactsContract` for arbitrary contacts.

Comment: Well, probably, but I have a lot of other permission code to change within the app, this is the first I started to change, so I need result to be fired :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just needed to remove from parent activity

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
...
}
```

and it works now.